# Platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a weird problem when I want to compile a Visual Studio 2012 solution via `msbuild` on the command line. Whatever I do, it exits with `Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid.` I have tried launching it via the regular command prompt, the Windows 7 SDK prompt, and all three command prompts included in VS2012. However, compiling in Visual Studio itself works.

`where msbuild` outputs:

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe`

Answer (score 7):

You have probably solved the problem yourself but perhaps it may help others with a similar problem. Try to set the VisualStudioVersion environment variable before running MSBuild, e.g

```
SET VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

There is a possibility that it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try passing the command line parameter **/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0** to MSBuild, when trying to build your project. It seems to have the same effect as setting the environment variable, in the above answer.